# How to create Unique constraint object for form validation?

Tags: forms, mongodb, symfony, validation, symfony-2.1

I need to add the constraints on the fly in the controller action, so I'm doing this:

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique;

// ...

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
                new MinLength(8),
                new MaxLength(100),
                new Email(),
                new Unique(),
            ),
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

But I get this error:

`The options "fields" must be set for constraint Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique`

I tried passing an `array('fields' => 'email')` and `array('fields' => array('email'))` to the constructor but didn't work: `Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/www/dev/public/pixfeed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.php line 63`

So how do I use this class?

Comment: did you try new Unique(array('fields' => 'email')) or new Unique(array('fields' => array('email'))) ?

Comment: @getme Both. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The class Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique is usually used on the whole Document. E.g.

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="users")
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="email")
 */
class User
```

Which in my eyes makes a lot more sense on ORM/ODM level, than just check if the users imput is unique.
But if you are force to do it in Form, you could write a [custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Comment: If I do this, I won't be able to login (for example), because it will check for the uniqueness of the email. And if I add validation groups, the class will become a mess of annotations. For every form I will have to add another validation group in each constraint in each property of the document. It also makes it harder to extend.